# Javascript include technique with dynamic SRC="url"

Tags: javascript, performance, html

Is it possible (and a good idea) to pass dynamic data to a JavaScript include file via a hash url?

Such as:

```
<head> <script src="scripts.js#x=123&y=456"></script> </head>
```

I am looking for an alternative to inline js in dynamically built pages:

```
<head> 
    <script src="scripts.js#x=123&y=456"></script> 
    <script>
       $( document ).ready(function() {
          pageInit(123, 456)
       });
    </script>
</head>
```

Is it a good idea to avoid inline js? How can you pass dynamic data without ajax which creates a needless roundtrip network request?

**Note:** The hash bang url is a special because the browsers ignore the hash portion of the url when checking the cache. At least for html files.

So all of these will reuse the index.html file it is in the cache:

```
index.html
index.html#x=123
index.html#x=345345
index.html#x=2342&y=35435
```

This same principle should hold true for javascript files.  What I hope to achieve is to reuse the cache version of script.js from page to page.

Going to index.php, include this:

```
<head> <script src="scripts.js#x=123&y=456"></script> </head>
```

Then going to fun.php include this

```
<head> <script src="scripts.js#x=898756465&y=5678665468456"></script> </head>
```

Then going to see.php include this

```
<head> <script src="scripts.js#session=887987979&csrf_token=87965468796"></script> </head>
```

From page view to page view, pass whatever info the page needs via the hash bang while at the same time reuse scirpt.js from cache.

So, is it possible to read the hash bang info from within the scirpts.js?

Comment: Not exactly a question for stackoverflow, by the way passing the data through URL you gain the ability to cache the script with these specific values, instead you can't cache an inline-javascript-code.

Comment: stackoverlflow seems like the only and best place to ask this question.   Regarding cache, the hash (#) in the the url insrtructs the browser that is ok to use the cached version of the page.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity — The fragment id has nothing to do with caching.

Comment: Are you saying the js sent to the page will be different based on the args?  Meaning `scripts.js#x=123&y=456` would have different source than `scripts.js#x=abc&y=def`? (and the `#` is a typo, right?)

Comment: @gfrobenius, yes the x and y will change with each page request.  The hash # has special meaning in urls, see update.

Comment: At the point it executes I don't think JavaScript has any idea about the request that was made to retrieve it, so there'd be no way to get the "parameters" after the hash in the URL of the `<script>` tag. The major issues with inline JavaScript are re-usability and maintainability; if you're *only* using a `<script>` tag to call an initialisation function there shouldn't be too much to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. This sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML file you are creating is dynamic, then just create inline JavaScript. Writing an include will just create an extra request from the browser, which you can avoid in the first place.

**Edit**:
just include a JavaScript file that reads the URL, you don't need to pass any variables (but of course, you also could):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // pseudo code
    hashbang = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
    if (hashbang.x && hashbang.y) {
        pageInit(hashbang.x, hashbang.y);
    } else if (hashbang.csrf_token) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: For the first page request, a round trip is created.  The 2nd request, the cache version is used.

Comment: So, if the URL changes (different x and y) you want the browser to use the same HTML, but different JavaScript?

Comment: I've added further clarification in the question...see update. I want different html pages to use the same javascript file from cache while while at the same time pass different hash bang info.

Comment: I would still hold that it makes more sense to create the JavaScript dynamic. What are you trying to achieve by having the file served by cache?

Comment: @Sonata I don't think the JavaScript itself is dynamic, only the values of some variables vary between pages (I could be wrong). Generating an entirely new script every time seems like overkill if that is the case.

Comment: The javascript file is 5000 lines long and is static and cached by the browser for 1 year.  Inline javascript hinders performance.

Comment: I will try your posted solution. I am wondering if will pull the hashbang from index.php or from script.js

Comment: My solution is for index.php :-)